regex returns more data than it should
please read before you comment.
im trying to make a simple website scraper but i run into this error, it scrapes urls for scripts and its apparently capturing :
SCRIPT URL : https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=youtube&uilel=3&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26hl%3Den-GB%26next%3D%252Fsignin_passive%26feature%3Dpassive&hl=en-GB" style="display: none"><input id="search"... etc
using this script:
import re
import requests
sitemap = requests.get("https://youtube.com").text
javascriptmatches = re.findall("src=\"(https?://.*?\.js)\??.*?\"",sitemap)
for x in javascriptmatches:
  print(x)

update: i'm using the built in "re" library.

Not clear. Your sample text does not contain .js. And it starts not with src. Are you sure you show the string you wanted to show? What are you looking for, informally? HTTPS URLs with the name of JavaScript file at the end?

ye thats why im questioning it... it doesnt start with src nor end with js yet its giving me this output

I don't see what Regex library you use, but usually you can do it without lookarounds. If you can access match groups, you can find an inner group that contains all from https:// to .js. Your pattern with src= is incorrect because the HTML code (it looks like HTML) can also contain any number of space characters around =.

yeah problem is its printing out EXCESSIVE DATA that i DO NOT WANT i need it to print just the full script url including https i just want a simple regex script omfg

Why this ??.?" part at the end? After this group, you only need a ". Instead of .? inside group, you need to have * characters from a certain charset, those that cannot appear in a URL after URLEncode. For example. the " character itself will be URL-Encoded as %22.

because sometimes js links have ?version=3 or something like that and i just wanna make sure

js links have ?version=3? What do you mean? Could you show the example of your valid URLs? You should have done it in the very beginning. Could you show the text samples in your question?

im gonna update the script soo its more complete and shows exactly where its getting data from and an example is https://roblox.com/js/hsts.js?v=3, only one i know of atm but i ran into it while testing my script

Got it, thank you.

Obligatory post about the futility of trying to parse X/HTML with regular expressions. Use a DOM parser instead.

yeah idk about a dom parser or how they work but i was able to find a multiple regex solution that gets just about every script, surprisingly chatgpt was able to generate it after about 10-20 tries

.*? means "match the fewest characters needed to make the rest work." If there is a .js that comes way at the end of the string, the .*? will eat up all the characters in between (even if some of them are "). it doesn't mean "match the fewest characters necessary to match the next part of the regex, and if that succeeds but a later part of the regex fails, just give up instead of trying harder." The .*? will try as hard as possible.

This question is similar to: Need to extract all links from script tag HTML Python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For some reason its ignoring the "src=\" part of the regex string, the script url that you mention that doesn't end with .js actually does end with that after 20k characters, after finding the end of the actual 9th match.
You can use this instead to find the src from <scripts/> from HTML websites:
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    javascriptmatches = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "script":
            for i in attrs:
                if "src" in i:
                    self.javascriptmatches.append(i[1])

        return super().handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
    
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        return super().handle_endtag(tag)
    
    def handle_data(self, data):
        return super().handle_data(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sitemap = requests.get("https://youtube.com").text
    Parser = MyHTMLParser()
    Parser.feed(sitemap)
    print(Parser.javascriptmatches)

This code handles the sitemap as an HTML file and not a string only appending to the match list if a tag <script> has a src attribute.

got it to work and grabs 10/16 urls, i think the problem is im trying to grab urls that aren't loaded into the site yet (aka another script loads that script somehow)
